# PHP DateTime in FOR loop results in identical objects

Tags: php, datetime

This

```
$date = new DateTime();
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $dates[$i] = $date;
    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
var_dump($dates);
```

gives me an array of identical date objects, all of, say, 16 August if today was 12 August.

Any ideas?

PS. Change $date in the loop to $date->getTimeStamp, for example, and it works as expected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because modify() acts upon the object itself; and you're building an array with 5 pointers to the ***same*** object, which is modified every iteration of the loop, so they'll all point to a DateTime object that has been modified to the last date

```
$date = new DateTime();
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $dates[$i] = clone $date;
    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
```